# Wildcard aliases in postfix?

Tags: postfix, alias

is there  way to specify wildcard aliases in postfix virtual table?

eg.

```
support+*@foo.bar
```

gets sent to

```
support+*@bar.foo
```

in this way i want to achieve that all mails with a support+Project@foo.bar address get redirected to another server..

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`regex table`](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) or [`pcre_table`](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html) as one of your [`alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps) (or [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps)). You consider using [`transport_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) if you want the mail delivered to another box without aliasing.

Comment: Please provide an explicit example instead of just references.