# How do I setup a catch-all email in postfix

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

I configured a mail server on ubuntu with postfix ([follow this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/137901/50001))

Now I would like to set a catch-all email.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you specify what version of Ubuntu and Postfix you are using? This could help others give you a proper answer.

Comment: You need to configure a catch-all alias to handle this.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/431769/wildcard-aliases-in-postfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Set up an account for that address.
2. Set up a "catch-all" address which will receive the messages for any otherwise undefined address.